# XSLT : Return tabular data that includes element values between two numbers

Tags: xslt

I am trying to perform an XSL transformation that looks at an XML file and returns, in an HTML table, any item for which a given element has a value that falls between two numbers. So far, I am able to successfully grab the items that are equal to or greater than the bottom number (230000), but I have yet to be able to restrict the output so that it does not include any of the items that are above the top number (100000000). Here is the existing code:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="edt/ce">
    <xsl:if test="(number >= 230000)">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="number"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="desc"/></td>
    </tr>
     </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
```

With this code, my HTML output correctly includes any item for which the *number* element has a value that is greater than or equal to 230000. I now need to further restrict the output so that no items in the HTML output have a *number* element that is equal to or greater than 100000000.

I have tried all sorts of expressions to make this happen, but thus far I have not been able to get the desired result. I suspect that the correct expression employs some conjunction of the minimum and maximum numeric values, but my research has yet to deliver fruit.

Comment: You should post a representative XML source, your complete XSLT code and the output expect.

Comment: We can't tell you what you did wrong unless you tell us what you did.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<xsl:if test="(number(number) &gt;= 230000 and number(number) &lt; 100000000)">
```

**Edit**:

since comparing using `<=, <, >= or >` converts the objects to numbers a explicit conversion is unnecessary. [See i.e. this explanation](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/operator_less_than.html)

```
<xsl:if test="(number &gt;= 230000 and number &lt; 100000000)">
```

will do as well.

Comment: Why do you think it's necessary to use the `number()` function here?

Comment: You are correct. Comparing using < and > converts the objects automatically to numbers . I will correct the answer

Comment: Thanks. Your edited suggestion seems to have done the trick. I am now getting the correct output in the HTML table.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<xsl:if test="(number >= 230000)">
```

try:

```
<xsl:if test="100000000 >= number and number >= 230000">
```

or even better, do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="edt/ce[100000000 >= number and number >= 230000]">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="number"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="desc"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

*Untested, because no reproducible example was provided.*

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried both of your suggestions, but unfortunately, neither one is doing the trick. In the first case, the HTML table is generated without any data in it. In the second case, the HTML output is a bunch of jumbled code, which tells me that there is probably a syntax error somewhere in the XSL.

Comment: @Marconi Please edit your question and add a [mcve] showing an example XML input, your current XSLT code and the expected output.

Comment: I had to mess around with the numeric values a bit, but the code structure suggested in the second answer is working for me now:

'code'<xsl:if test="(number &gt;= 230000000 and number &lt;=100000000)">